# Deleting duplicates a linked lists Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to implement a method that deletes all the duplicates from a linked list. I've managed to take care of the tail. In other words, if the tail's `data` was a duplicate, the program wouldn't throw an `exception error`. Now, I'm trying to take care of the head such that if the `head`'s data is a duplicate, I want to set the `head` = `head.next` so that the duplicate is no longer in the linked list. However my method `deleteDuplicates` does not handle the `head`. Anybody have suggestions to fix this problem?

```
class Node {
        private Node next = null; 
        private int data; 

        public Node(int d) {
            data = d; 
        }

        void appendToTail(int d) {
            Node end = new Node(d); 
            Node n = this; 

            while(n.next != null) {
                n = n.next; 
            }
            n.next = end; 
        }

        void print() {
            Node n = this; 
            while(n != null) {
                System.out.println(n.data); 
                n = n.next; 
            }
        }

        Node deleteDuplicates(Node head, int d) {
            Node n = head;
            if(n.data == d) {
                head = head.next; 
                n = n.next; 
            }
            while(n != null) {
                if(n.next.data == d) {
                    if(n.next == null && n.next.data == d) {
                        return head;
                    }
                    n.next = n.next.next;
                }
                n = n.next; 
            }
            return head; 
        }

        public static void main(String [] args) {
            Node x = new Node(9); 
            x.appendToTail(5);
            x.appendToTail(9);
            x.appendToTail(6);
            x.appendToTail(9);  
            x.appendToTail(7);
            x.appendToTail(9);  
            x.appendToTail(8); 
            x.appendToTail(9); 
            x.deleteDuplicates(x, 9); 
            x.print(); 
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Is this for homework? If it isn't you can convert the list to a `HashSet` which removes duplicates. I doubt it is for homework or else you wouldn't be allowed to use `Node`... If it is for homework well it probably has something to do with the first `if` statement in `deleteDuplicates()` which looks like it just moves to the next node if the value is equal

Comment: Which is duplicate criteria ? identify, equality, another one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you haven't reassigned your head after deletion.
If you modify it as follows, I think your head deletion problem will be solved.

`x = x.deleteDuplicates(x, 9);`

Needless to say, there are other efficient methods like hashing which can be used to bring down the time complexity of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You want to keep removing the head as long as it matches the value. So replace the `if` with a `while`:

```
Node n = head;
while (n != null && n.data == d) {
    n = n.next; 
}
head = n;
```

You have other problems too. This line for example will raise a null pointer exception when `n.next` is null:

```
if(n.next == null && n.next.data == d) {
```

Fixing your while loop:

```
while (n.next != null) {
    if (n.next.data == d) {
        n.next = n.next.next;
    } else {
        n = n.next;
    }
}
```

Lastly, the method name you chose is very misleading.
"deleteDuplicates" suggests deleting *all* duplicates,
for example:

> ```
> from: 9->5->6->9->7->9->8->9  
>   to: 9->5->6->7->8
> ```

It would make sense to call this method just `delete`.

#### Putting it together

With the above corrections applied, the method becomes:

```
Node delete(Node head, int d) {
    Node n = head;

    // skip consecutive d values at head
    while (n != null && n.data == d) {
        n = n.next; 
    }
    head = n;

    // skip d values
    while (n.next != null) {
        if (n.next.data == d) {
            n.next = n.next.next;
        } else {
            n = n.next;
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a container of unique objects, the best way to go is to have these objects implement the .equals() and .hashCode() methods so you can use a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) to handle the uniqueness logic.

Equality can be easily implemented as an addition of all the class' fields equality, and hashCode from a hash of the concatenation of all the class' fields hashCodes.

If you need them to be linked for some reason, [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) is there for you.

Example with Integers :

```
LinkedHashSet<Integer> myCollection = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
myCollection.add(5);
myCollection.add(3);
myCollection.add(2);
myCollection.add(5);
myCollection.add(2);
System.out.println(myCollection);
// prints [5, 3, 2]
```

An example with a custom class can be found [here](https://ideone.com/Go3nNW).

Comment: Still wont work... you need to implement hash code and equals after that the next part will be different so it wont work. FYI not the down voter so i can't fix that for you !

Comment: @StackFlowed I tested my solution with an initial LinkedList<Integer> and it worked fine. I think the elements need to implement Comparable, I'll try to add that to my answer somehow. No problem about the downvote, it's just sad if OP's code is for production rather than exercise that he basically reinvents the wheel.

Comment: It will work for Integer as all that is implemented try for a class that you have written then try you will see what I'm saying.

Comment: @StackFlowed you're right, HashSet.add() is based on .equals rather than .compareTo. I was pretty sure there was an Interface guaranteeing usability in a Set so Comparable looked like the obvious choice, but sadly I'm mistaken. Do you remember where the .hashCode comes into play? I couldn't find it in the HashSet documentation.

Comment: @StackFlowed nevermind, Object says the hashCode is used in HashMaps, which backs HashSets ; I'm fixing my answer

Answer (score 0):

Verified by running code. You code should look like this :

```
x.deleteDuplicates(x, 9).print();
```

Then the delete method should be :

```
Node deleteDuplicates(Node head, int d) {
    Node nextNode=head;
    if(head.data == d) {
        if(head.next==null) {
            return null;
        }
         return deleteDuplicates(head.next, d);
    }
    Node previous=head;
    while(nextNode.next != null) {
        nextNode=nextNode.next;
        if(nextNode.data == d) {
            previous.next=nextNode.next;
        }
        previous=nextNode;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Output :

```
5
6
7
8
```

In the you check if the head node needs to be deleted you make the next node as head node. You also check if last node is to be deleted then you make the previous nodes next as null.

Answer (score 0):

Something like (untested code):

The idea is that for each element, traverse the rest of the list and remove and duplicates of the current element

```
public void deleteDupes(Node head) {
  if (head == null || head.next == null) {
    return;
  }
  Node current = head;
  while (current != null) {
    Node runner = head;
    while (runner.next != null) {
      if (runner.next.val == current.val) {
        runner.next = runner.next.next;
      }
      else {
        runner = runner.next;
      }
    }
    current = current.next;
  }
}
```